# ExtJS: Using gridpanel filter Header ignores/resets the store filter that I added

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am loading my store and grid panel and assigning a filter like so

```
myGrid.store.filter('enabled', 'true');
```

This is to filter out records that are not enabled. This works, my gridpanel initially shows all records that are enabled equal to true. Then when I apply a filter using the gridpanel header and search for a record that I know has enabled set to false NOW appears.

The initial gridpanel list after initially assigning `store.filter(....)` removes all records that don't have enabled equal to true but filtering with the header includes it in the new filter.

I followed the docs here :
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature

So I have something like this :

```
 Ext.apply(me, {
        width: 500,
        height: 250,
        store: 'BlockItems',
        features: [{
            ftype: 'filters',
            local: true,
```

After removing the filter from the header I am left with my list again but now it includes records that `enabled != true` and also `enabled == true` i.e All records.

I am very confused. I have filtered my store, so why is the grid "header filter" no complying with the filter I initially added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new filters by creating new instances of [`Ext.util.Filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter) and add them to the filters of the `store`.

I have the following code in my `select event` of a `gridheader combobox`:

```
this.up('grid').getStore().filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
    anyMatch: false,
    disableOnEmpty: true,
    property: field.up('gridcolumn').dataIndex,
    value   : field.getValue()
}));
```

And this is the code of the `keyup` of the `combobox`:

```
if (Ext.isEmpty(field.getValue()) && isValidKey === true) {
    this.up('grid').getStore().filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
        anyMatch: false,
        disableOnEmpty: true,
        property: field.up('gridcolumn').dataIndex,
        value   : field.getValue()
    }));
}
```

And this is the keyup of a `gridheader textfield`:

```
grid.getStore().filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
    anyMatch: true,
    disableOnEmpty: true,
    property: field.up('gridcolumn').dataIndex,
    value   : field.getValue()
}));
```

They work perfectly together as you can see in my [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ts4)

Comment: Thats great, thanks. How do you catch the even of the grid header combo ? Do you have your listeners ? Could you post some code?

Comment: It's all in the Fiddle. I have created a filtercombo which extends from a combobox. That filtercombo I declared in the view. If you look in the filtercombo you can see I listen to the events there..

Comment: What if I want to keep them in sync ? Custom filter and default's framework 'gridfilter' plugin ? The ideea is that I would like to programatically filter a grid and reflect this in 'gridfilter' plugin. If I do store filter like you do that's not happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. If you use column filters, it removes all other filters from the store, since it can't know whether you want to keep them or not.

You have three possibilities. The most thorough would be to have only the enabled records in the store, if you don't intend to show the disabled ones at all.

If you don't want to do that, you can either listen to the filterchange event and add the enabled filter back after every filterchange (check whether it is already added, or else you get an infinite loop), or you can redefine how each of the column filters should work, so they obey to your special needs:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature-cfg-filters